Librosa can't load recorded audio from microphone
Experimenting with streamlit, I recorded audio using microphone with wav output using this library
import streamlit as st
from st_audiorec import st_audiorec
import librosa

wav_audio_data = st_audiorec()
if wav_audio_data is not None:
    y, sr = librosa.load(wav_audio_data, sr=None)

I got an error saying:
LibsndfileError: Error opening b'RIFF,@\x0b\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00  
.... 
System error.

I was expecting to call librosa.load() using audio that is recorded from microphone with streamlit as interface.

IIUC st_audiorec() returns a string (or some other kind of buffer) with the audio data.
According to the documentation, librosa.load() expects the path to a file containing the audio data. Note the error message:

Error opening b'RIFF,@\x0b\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00

It tried to open a file named RIFF,@\x0b\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00  .... Of course it would fail, there is no such file!
You can do any of these things:

put that audio data in a file (maybe a named pipe?); or
find a function in Librosa which would consume the data in the format coming from st_audiorec();
use a different library to load or to play the audio.


librosa.load takes a path to a file on disk as input. The soundfile library on the other hand takes a file-like object as input. You can get that from your string data using the io module.
